# Will allowing users to Search by any fields slow the system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am developing an internal website for a company consist of 5 employees. They gonna use this website mainly to store records and look up, and Only the employees(5 people) will have access to this website.

Question:

Will allowing the user to search by any filed slows down the system? the reason why I am asking is some of the tables has around 20 fields and the database has 40 tables in total. So I just wondering if that can be a problem...!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add indexes to those fields in the database you should be fine. It will definitely consume more space on your database server but won't slow down the application. Basically it's performance at the cost of disk space (yeah, there's no free lunch). Oh, and don't forget, the more indexes you have, the slower the inserts and updates to this database might become.

So if you had to draw one conclusion from this answer, that would be: go ahead and measure. And if you are not satisfied with the results try limiting the number of fields you can search by to see if this might improve the performance of your application. And do this until you have met the goal you have defined when designing the performance specifications of your application.